# Android Animation not Animating

Tags: android, animation

I have an animation set on an ImageButton that is Invisible, then on a callback gets set to be visible and should start to animate.

I set my animation up like this

```
    showBuildingTapAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.main_button_tap);
```

and call it like this

```
if(showBuildingCollectionNavButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    showBuildingCollectionNavButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    showBuildingCollectionNavButton.requestLayout();
    showBuildingTapAnimation.start();
}
```

and I have also tried this:

```
if(showBuildingCollectionNavButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
    showBuildingCollectionNavButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    showBuildingCollectionNavButton.requestLayout();
    showBuildingCollectionNavButton.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getApplicationContext(), R.anim.main_button_tap));
}
```

and this

```
    if(showBuildingCollectionNavButton.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
        showBuildingCollectionNavButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        showBuildingCollectionNavButton.requestLayout();
        showBuildingCollectionNavButton.startAnimation(showBuildingTapAnimation);
    }
```

My animation itself is here:

```
<scale
    android:duration="075"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.09"
    android:toYScale="1.09"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
/>

<scale
    android:duration="075"
    android:startOffset="075"
    android:fromXScale="1.09"
    android:fromYScale="1.09"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
/>
```

I am calling requestLayout() as a few of the posts here talked about issues when the asset was gone or invisible that it wasn't updating...

I think the real issue may be with the context that I am passing into the loadAnimation() call - as I am in a FragmentActivity here...

Thoughts ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are displaying your animations for 75 + 75 ms . They are animated but you can not observe them (especially a scale that small)

Comment: oh jesus. lemme verify that!